# Collecting database changes for later

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

I'm currently facing a problem with my game, namely that it's gained a lot of activity lately.

The premise of the game involves making interactions with other players to give their characters EXP (in the hopes they will return the favour so you both get rewarded). However, this means there are a LOT of `` UPDATE x SET `exp` = ? WHERE `id` = ? ``-type queries.

In addition to this, a random user is chosen to receive double EXP, and this effect is "contagious" in that it passes to another based on activity during its time with the current host. This makes that particular user very desirable and likely to receive EXP, resulting in a concentration of activity there. (Race conditions aren't really a concern here, any EXP lost in a race condition won't end the world)

As a test I have temporarily disabled EXP gain and the server lag was greatly reduced as a result (still collecting results on that fact). This makes me think that the EXP gain is indeed the culprit here.

I already have Memcached saving the data, so for the most part the database is only being hit with `UPDATE` queries, very few `SELECT`s. What I would like to do is accumulate these EXP gains and apply them every so often via a Cron script to try and reduce the activity on that table. Essentially, rather than every single user's interaction modifying the table, it would be stored and then the updates applied by a single process.

However, the problem I then face is "how do I store these TODO EXP gains"?

While I can use Memcached to store them, Memcached isn't very good for arbitrary key/value pairs (eg. key=ID of thing to apply EXP to, value=EXP gained) and I'm unsure how I might retrieve that list.

The other option is to use a separate table that just lists the EXP gains. It would literally be `` CREATE TABLE `expgains` (`apply_to` INT..., `deltaexp` INT...) `` with the idea being it will only contain EXP changes (maybe a hundred thousand rows instead of ~20M) and no other data. The Cron script could then atomically read and wipe the table and apply those EXP changes at once.

However, I don't know if moving the problem will really fix it.

Any other ideas how to go about doing this? Or opinions on the above ideas?

Comment: I have further confirmed that this EXP gain is responsible for most, if not all, of the recent issues.

Comment: I have "fixed" the problem to some extent by allowing this particular query to ignore errors during the update. Since it still stored in Memcached, it will apply the EXP gain next time an interaction is made instead. This seems to be working, but it feels dirty!